# ng-disabled not evaluating every time on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm actually trying to disable a pair of radio buttons on the click of a button in my angularjs application.

Code Snippet of radio buttons is provided below here:

```
<div class="col-xs-4 btn-group" id="challenge-radio-btn">
    <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="trigger" ng-value=false
              name="{{path.id}} notChallengeTriggr"
              ng-change = "onChange(x,y,z,w,a)"
              ng-disabled="campaign.editnotscheduled || ischallengeTrigger"
              checked> No
    </label>
    <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" ng-model="trigger" ng-value=true
              name="{{path.id}} challengeTriggr"
              ng-change = "onChange(x,y,z,w,a)"
              ng-disabled="campaign.editnotscheduled || ischallengeTrigger"> Yes
    </label>
</div>
```

On click of the button, I have even tried printing the value of the expression which is getting evaluated inside of ng-disabled. On every click of this button, the value becomes true(as I have written js code-behind to make this true). Even the value of the ng-disabled expression is true, the radio buttons are not getting disabled.

On debugging, I had found a particular scenario where it wasn't working. Once I click on a specific dropdown in my application, after that if I come back & click on edit button to check whether these radio buttons are disabled or not. At that time, radio buttons are not disabled even though the ng-disabled expression value is true.

Comment: Should `ng-disabled="editnotscheduled` not be `ng-disabled="campaign.editnotscheduled`?

Comment: My bad. Typo error. Made the edit required. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic of OR is causing the problem.

ng-disabled="campaign.editnotscheduled || ischallengeTrigger" checked>
ng-disabled="editnotscheduled || ischallengeTrigger">

If either of them is false.then your button should get disabled.

Comment: It is an OR condition, right. Here, if anyone of the variable is true, then the condition evaluates to true. In my case, `ischallengeTrigger` is true. Hence, this condition always evaluates to true & eventually the radio buttons should be disabled. 

Thanks for the response. I presume you have confused my OR condition with AND condition truth table.